# Riemann Integrability and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

James Stewart's text Calculus with Early Transcendentals 7ed. pg 388 states:

FTC: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then the function defined by $g(x) = \int_a^xf(t)dt,\: x\in[a,b]$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $g'=f$.

Charles Pugh relaxes the conditions in his book Real Mathematical Analysis on pg. 171 by stating:

FTC: If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable then its indefinite integral $F(x) = \int_a^xf(t)dt$ is a continuous function of $x$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$ at all points $x$ at which $f$ is continuous.

On pg. 163 Pugh defines Riemann Integrability as follows:

A function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and its set of discontinuity points is a zero set(measure $0$).

Now consider the function $f(x) = x^{-1/3}$ and define the function $g(x) = \int_a^xf(t)dt = \int_a^xt^{-1/3}dt$.

$f(x)$ is not bounded at $x=0$ where we have a vertical asymptote.[image: $f(x) = x^{-1/3}$]

However, suppose $a<0$ and $x>0$ or $a>0$ and $x<0$, then the integral function $g(x)$ will, in a sense, cross this vertical asymptote. The improper integral limits from left and right at zero converge and so it seems we may write $g(x) = \frac{3}{2}\left(x^{2/3}-a^{2/3}\right)$ which is a continuous function for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ that has a cusp at zero.[image]

Questions:

1. If the improper integral converges at $x_0$ where $f(x_0)=\pm\infty$ can we relax the boundedness requirement in Pugh's definition?
2. Would the resulting integral function always either have a finite discontinuity or cusp at $x_0$?
3. What resources would you suggest I read to investigate related phenomena?

Comment: Usually, this is called the "Differentiation theorem" or sometimes the "First FTC". The name "FTC" by itself is generally reserved for the other direction (the "2nd FTC" when this one is called the "1st FTC"). I.e., that $\int_a^bf'dx = f(b) - f(a)$. And note that the full conclusion of the theorem doesn't hold for improper integrals: if $F(x) = \int_a^xf(t)dt$, then $F$ will not be differentiable at values of $x$ for which $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ is improper.

Comment: Thx Paul, I see your point but wouldn't the $x$ values where the integral is improper be excluded from the statement about $F'=f$ at the end of Pugh's differentiation theorem? I suppose what I think might be true is the following statement: $f$ is Riemann integrable if it has a set of discontinuities that has measure zero and on those discontinuities where $f$ is unbounded, the improper integral converges. Then apply the differentiation theorem to this more general class of functions.

Comment: But that isn't an extension. The theorem already states that the derivative of the integral is the integrand everywhere that the integral is proper, and your versopm excepts the points where the integral is improper, so you haven't gained anything not in the original.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair ok, one final question. If you were asked to find the domain of $g(x) = \int_a^xf(t)dt$ and $f(t)$ had an infinite discontinuity at $x_0$ s.t.$a<x_0<x$ and was continuous otherwise, would you always restrict the domain to be $[a,x_0)$? Would it depend on whether the improper integral converged at $x_0$?

Comment: Obviously, I would restrict it if the improper integral did not converge from both sides. But otherwise, I would investigate what the asker meant. Did they intend only proper Riemann integration? Then yes. Are they just after an anti-derivative of maximal domain and didn't realize that expressing it this way puts on additional restrictions? Then no. Context is important here.